# Adding custom tags style in Select2 MultiSelect Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

so I'm using Select2 4 library (https://select2.github.io/) and I have a problem.

```
<select id="test" multiple style="width:800px;">
    <option value="a">aaaaa</option>
    <option value="b">bbbbb</option>
    <option value="c">cccc</option>
    <option value="d">ddddd</option>
</select>

(...)

$("#test").select2({
   tags: true,
   tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
})
```

This is generating, after making some choices DOM element, which contains some `<li>`s

So - it works fine. But I need to add my classes to those `<li>` elements after changing. I don't know how to do that because Select2 rewrites my classes instantly after adding.

I've tried something like this:

```
selectEl.change(function() {
  var elements = $('.select2-selection > ul > li');
  elements.each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('my-test-class');
  });
});
```

but nothing changes (except for the last element, which is an input). I mean - I think it works, but Select2 instantly rewrites it.

I've tried doing it using change, select2:select listeners and none of those works fine.

The idea is - adding 'select2-auto' to `<li>`s that are chosen from the drop-down list, and 'select-manual' class to the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `templateSelection:` for custom tags styles please find below snippet for your reference..

```
templateSelection: function(selection) {
        if(selection.selected) {
            return $.parseHTML('<span class="customclass">' + selection.text + '</span>');
        }
        else {
            return $.parseHTML('<span class="customclass">' + selection.text + '</span>');
        }
    }
```

```js
$("#test").select2({
   tags: true,
   allowClear: true, //
   closeOnSelect: false,
   tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
   templateSelection: function(selection) {
        if(selection.selected) {
            return $.parseHTML('<span class="customclass">' + selection.text + '</span>');
        }
        else {
            return $.parseHTML('<span class="customclass">' + selection.text + '</span>');
        }
    }

});

$("#test").on("select2:select", function(e) { 
$("li[aria-selected='true']").addClass("customclass");
$("li[aria-selected='false']").removeClass("customclass");
$('.select2-search-choice:not(.my-custom-css)', this).addClass('my-custom-css');
});

$("#test").on("select2:unselect", function(e) { 
$("li[aria-selected='false']").removeClass("customclass");
});
```

```css
.selectRow {
    display : block;
    padding : 20px;
}
.select2-container {
    width: 200px;
}

.customclass
{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select id="test" multiple style="width:800px;">
    <option value="a">aaaaa</option>
    <option value="b">bbbbb</option>
    <option value="c">cccc</option>
    <option value="d">ddddd</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`dropdownCssClass` Property use for adding class to the select2 drop-down menu. Something like this,

```
$("#test").select2({
     tags: true,
     tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
     containerCssClass: "my-test-class",
     dropdownCssClass: "test-class"
 });
```

I hope this will work for you. Thanks.

Comment: i think `dropdownCssClass`  add class to select2's dropdown container not selected `li` isn't it?

Comment: @Curiousdev  still available in  `select2.full.min.js`

Comment: jquery-3.1.1.min.js?ver=v1.9.1.1.25:2 Uncaught Error: No select2/compat/dropdownCss

    selectEl.select2({
      tags: true,
      tokenSeparators: [' '],
      containerCssClass: "my-test-class",
      dropdownCssClass: "test-class"
    });

Comment: @alanmcknee put a comma `,` after `tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']`

Comment: @Curiousdev it is there

Comment: @alanmcknee  instead of `select2.min.js` try using `select2.full.min.js` , `containerCssClass` is not available in `select2.min.js`

Comment: @alanmcknee i'm not sure about this answer but regarding your `Uncaught Error` i have edited this answer paste it in your app and check if it's working or not

Comment: @shivamGupta - ok, but It only has added 'my-test-class' to the container, not to the `<li>`s

Comment: @alanmcknee now you can target as `.my-test-class ul li{ ... }`

Comment: @shivamGupta - I need to add it after every change as I said before

Comment: @alanmcknee your change event seems to be working fine, on what event you loose classes from `li`

Comment: @alanmcknee please find [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ad7A/671/) and let me know if you are looking similar like this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#test").select2({
   tags: true,
   allowClear: true, //
   closeOnSelect: false,
   tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
});

$("#test").on({
  "select2:select": function(e) { 
      $("li[aria-selected='true']").addClass("customclass");
      $("li[aria-selected='false']").removeClass("customclass");
    },
    "select2:opening": function(e) { 
        setTimeout(function(){
          $("li[aria-selected='true']").addClass("customclass");
          $("li[aria-selected='false']").removeClass("customclass");
        },0)
    },
    "select2:unselect" : function(e) { 
        $("li[aria-selected='false']").removeClass("customclass");
    }
});
```

```css
.selectRow {
      display : block;
      padding : 20px;
  }
  .select2-container {
      width: 200px;
  }

  .customclass
  {
    color:red;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>


<select id="test" multiple style="width:800px;">
    <option value="a">aaaaa</option>
    <option value="b">bbbbb</option>
    <option value="c">cccc</option>
    <option value="d">ddddd</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nope ;) I need to add classes to li.select2-selection__choice. But thanks